# How to get context specific data from PostSharp events

Tags: c#, postsharp

I'm considering using `PostSharp` to capture events as they occur. However, the big issue I see is that part of an `Event` in my system is at LEAST a primary key to the element that changed.

When I define my custom attribute, I can require certain data points but they are all *static*.  Can I build my attribute to know how to access the pk?

Something like

```
[Event(GetPrimaryKey = (Dictionary<string, object> args)=> { return args["UserId"]; })]
public string CreateUser()
{
    ...
}
```

which in the event could be used

```
public override void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    var key = this.getPrimaryKey(args.Arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you need to take a bit different approach since values that you can set in attribute specification are fairly limited.

The best approach is to mark the primary key parameter with an attribute and then, at PostSharp's build time, find the parameter you need and store its position in the aspect. The aspect is then serialized and you can use this variable at runtime.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class EventKeyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[PSerializable]
public class EventAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    private int keyPosition;

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize( MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo )
    {
        this.keyPosition = -1;

        // Go through method's arguments and find the key position.
        foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
        {
            if (param.IsDefined(typeof(EventKeyAttribute)))
            {
                if (this.keyPosition != -1)
                {
                    // Build time error.
                    Message.Write( param, SeverityType.Error, "ERR001", $"Multiple parameters of {method} are marked with [EventKey]." );
                    return;
                }

                this.keyPosition = param.Position;
            }
        }

        if (this.keyPosition == -1)
        {
            // Build time error.
            Message.Write( method, SeverityType.Error, "ERR002", $"No parameter of {method} is marked with [EventKey]." );
        }
    }

    public override void OnSuccess( MethodExecutionArgs args )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"Key is: {args.Arguments[this.keyPosition]}" );
    }
}
```

Afterward, you can simply apply both attributes on a method:

```
[Event]
static void Foo(int a, [EventKey]int b, int c)
{
}
```